# How to set a character in C++?

Tags: c++, char, set, byte

This is probably very obvious, in fact so obvious that no C++ reference I could find online cares to document it.

I need to know how to set the byte value of a `char` in C/C++. For example, if I want the byte value 233 in the char, how do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is too obvious:

```
char x = 233;
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know I could do that. All the docs always put the values between single quotes (i.e. they set the variable to a letter, not a number) so I assumed there was some conversion to do.

Comment: @Laurent: The quoted characters mean the same numeric values, it's just a different representation at compile time.

Comment: That's just to make it easier to find an 'a', which might have different code on different machines.

Comment: Is this technically UB if your char is signed and it cannot accommodate a value of 233?

Comment: @john - probably, but we don't know if it is signed, or how many bits there are in the char. Assigning outside of the allowed range will likely trigger a message from the compiler. For "a byte value" it might be better to use `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Assuming 8 bit signed char, then I think it is UB. I say the standard is crazy in it's integer overflow rules. People tell me I'm crazy and go on about obscure architectures where this stuff matters. Here, no less than three people post code that is incorrect, and this code receives 8 up votes (and counting). And yet, we all know that the code will work as intended! Something is wrong.

Comment: @John - On the compiler I use you an choose if you want the char to be signed or not. The question didn't say what compiler or options were used, so we don't know. If Laurent wants the value 233 in his char, we must assume that is a possible value or that the compiler will tell him otherwise.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Yes, I'm being completely off topic, and all the answers given here are fine by me. It's just this issue bugs me.

Answer (score 3):

A char is a 1byte int. So you can set the value in the same way as you would an int.

```
char c = 123;
char d = 0x12;
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
char x = 233;
```

Yea, literally as simple as that.